# Please differentiate between meta sites for beta versus normal sites, in the /sites method

Tags: feature-request, api, meta, api-v2.1, sites

Currently, in [the `/sites` method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites), a site can have a `site_state` of: `normal`, `open_beta`, `closed_beta`, or `linked_meta`.

This makes it easy to tell if a **main** site is in beta or not.  But it becomes a 2 or 3 step process to determine if a **meta** site is in beta -- rather than a straight table read.

For all meta sites in beta, please change the `site_state` to `linked_meta_beta` or similar.

Or add the `launch_date` field like normal, main sites have.

---

---

PS: I mainly care about beta sites because they are not in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE).  The problem that spawned this question could also be solved if `/sites` returned a value `data_in_data_explorer` -- set to true or false, for each site.